# Segmentation fault on merging threads (Perl)

Tags: multithreading, perl, segmentation-fault

I had some working code that I've tried to multithread using the tutorial on dreamincode: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/255487-multithreading-in-perl/

The example code there seems to work fine, but I can't for the life of me work out why mine isn't. From putting in debug messages it seems to get all the way to the end of the subroutine with all of the threads, and then sit there for a while before hitting a segmentation fault and dumping the core. That being said I've also not managed to find the core dump files anywhere (Ubuntu 13.10).

If anyone has any suggested reading, or can see the error in the rather messy code below I'd be eternally grateful.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Email::Valid;
use LWP::Simple;
use XML::LibXML;
use Text::Trim;
use threads;
use DB_File;

use Getopt::Long;

my $sourcefile   = "thislevel.csv";
my $startOffset = 0;
my $chunk = 10000;
my $num_threads = 8;

$result = GetOptions ("start=i" => \$startOffset,    # numeric
              "chunk=i" => \$chunk,    # numeric
                  "file=s"   => \$sourcefile,      # string
                  "threads=i" => \$num_threads,     #numeric
                  "verbose"  => \$verbose);  # flag


$tie = tie(@filedata, "DB_File", $sourcefile, O_RDWR, 0666, $DB_RECNO)
    or die "Cannot open file $sourcefile: $!\n";

my $filenumlines = $tie->length;

if ($filenumlines>$startOffset + $chunk){
    $numlines = $startOffset + $chunk;
} else {
    $numlines = $filenumlines;
}


open (emails, '>>emails.csv');
open (errorfile, '>>errors.csv');
open (nxtlvl, '>>nextlevel.csv');
open (donefile, '>>donelines.csv');
my $line = '';
my $found = false;

my $linenum=0;

my @threads = initThreads();



foreach(@threads){

    $_ = threads->create(\&do_search);

}


foreach(@threads){
    $_->join();
}


close nxtlvl;
close emails;
close errorfile;
close donefile;


sub initThreads{
    # An array to place our threads in
    my @initThreads;
    for(my $i = 1;$i<=$num_threads;$i++){
        push(@initThreads,$i);
    }
    return @initThreads;
}




sub do_search{
    my $id = threads->tid();

    my $linenum=$startOffset-1+$id;

    my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
    $parser->set_options({ recover           => 2,
                           validation        => 0,
                       suppress_errors   => 1,
                       suppress_warnings => 1,
                       pedantic_parser   => 0,
                       load_ext_dtd      => 0, });


    while ($linenum < $numlines) {

        $found = false;
        @full_line = split ',', $filedata[$linenum-1];

        $line = trim(@full_line[1]);
        $this_url = trim(@full_line[2]);
        print "Thread $id Scanning $linenum of $filenumlines\: ";
        printf "%.3f\%\n", 100 * $linenum / $filenumlines;

        my $content = get trim($this_url);

        if (!defined($content)) {

            print errorfile "$this_url, no content\n";

        }elsif (length($content)<100) {

            print errorfile "$this_url, short\n";

        }else {

            my $doc = $parser->load_html(string => $content);

            if(defined($doc)){

                for my $anchor ( $doc->findnodes("//a[\@href]") )
                {
                    $is_email = substr $anchor->getAttribute("href") ,7;
                    if(Email::Valid->address($is_email)) {
                        printf emails "%s, %s\n", $line, $is_email;
                        $found = true;
                    } else{
                        $link = $anchor->getAttribute("href");
                        if (substr lc(trim($link)),0,4 eq "http"){
                            printf nxtlvl "%s, %s\n", $line, $link;
                        } else {
                            printf nxtlvl "%s, %s/%s\n", $line, $line, $link;
                        }
                    }
                } 
            }
            if ($found=false){

                my @lines = split '\n',$content;

                foreach my $cline (@lines){
                    my @words = split ' ',$cline;
                        foreach my $word (@words) { 
                        my @subwords = split '"',$word ;
                        foreach my $subword (@subwords) {

                            if(Email::Valid->address($subword)) {
                                    printf emails "%s, %s\n", $line, $subword;  
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    }
            }
        }
        printf donefile "%s\n",$linenum;
        $linenum = $linenum + $num_threads;     
    }
    threads->exit();
}
```

Comment: That tutorial contains loads of shitty and/or useless code. Forget it and rather read the [threads](https://metacpan.org/pod/threads) documentation. I don't know why your code segfaults, it's probably the fault of some module you used (my money is on `DB_File`). That said I doubt your code worked in the non-threaded form: Perl doesn't have `true` or `false`, use `1` or `0` instead. Get warned about such things with `use strict; use warnings;` (`Perl::Critic` can also help).

Comment: Is DB_File thread-safe? Did you try with the latest version of Perl?

Comment: You're right that the true/false thing would have changed the behavior, so I've fixed that. The crash happens when the last thread gets to `threads->exit();`, where would I check if `DB_File` is thread-safe? There's nothing on it's CPAN page: [http://search.cpan.org/~pmqs/DB_File-1.831/DB_File.pm]

Comment: Threads require use of Thread safe libraries, DB_File appears to not be thread safe - http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=733599 (though it is an old post, I don't see any reason it magically changed without it being written in the product's man file)

Comment: Thanks to all - DB_File was causing the errors. I've coded this and other errors out and everything is again working well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to sundry coding errors that mean my code should never ever be used as an example for other visitors, `DB_File` is not a thread-safe module.

Annoyingly, and perhaps misleadingly, it works absolutely as it should do right up until you close the threads that have been successfully accessing the file throughout your code.